# GetWindowDC() equivalent in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

We can get the device context of the window (`GetWindowDC()`) in Windows desktop app, but in Windows Store app it fails the API support app. I am developing the Windows Store app in c#. Please let me know its equivalent method as my whole app depends on this.

UPDATE:
I am having an Drawing app, in which In Canvas I have added the TextBlock and wants to draw only on th Text, not outside. To acheiev this I have used (GetWindowDC()) and (GetPixel())  methods and then aaded the required check. And now my app has failed the Windows App Certification Kit test.

Comment: What is the use case? If you want to draw on a window, you have plenty of other supported ways.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a Win32 API function in Windows RT environment. Thats actually not possible, because a Windows Store application may run on any device with a Windows RT runtime (like tablets and mobile phones). Those environments does not support Win32 API functions.

Comment: Thanks! yes I know this can you please point me out about the equivalent method.

Comment: @MandeepKaur You should explain your use case. Why do you need the `DC`? It seems unnecessary in Windows Store apps. Please edit your question and explain your scenario, if possible (instead of adding comments here). This makes it a better question.

Comment: I have added some detail about my query in the "UPDATED" section, hope this will help you to give me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) of everything accessible in `WinRT`. Note you have an access to only a small subset of the `Win32 API` and it is wrapped through the `WinRT API`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have not found any equivalent method of it in this link..pls let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: @MandeepKaur I don't think there is equivalent API exposed.